# Can I use lua in the openresty nginx http block

Tags: openresty

I want to request some api and set the response as a nginx variable. But it says `"set_by_lua_block" directive is not allowed here`. How can I achieve this?

```
http {
  set_by_lua_block $hostIp {
    local http = require 'resty.http'
    local httpc = http.new()
    local res, err = httpc:request_uri('http://some-pai')
    local body, err = res:read_body()
    ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Using ngx.INFO")
    ngx.log(ngx.INFO, body)
    return body
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set_by_lua_block is not allowed in http context

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#set_by_lua

set_by_lua_* may be used within server context.

But your code will not work anyway because resty.http uses cosocket API.

> At least the following API functions are currently disabled within the
> context of set_by_lua:
>
> Output API functions (e.g., ngx.say and ngx.send_headers)
>
> Control API functions (e.g., ngx.exit)
>
> Subrequest API functions (e.g., ngx.location.capture and ngx.location.capture_multi)
>
> Cosocket API functions (e.g., ngx.socket.tcp and ngx.req.socket).
>
> Sleeping API function ngx.sleep.

If you really need to request something once before nginx start - write script and set environment variable. Then

```
set_by_lua $my_var 'return os.getenv("MY_VAR")';
```

Comment: I'm now using script to generate `nginx.conf`. I was thinking lua can handle this.